# List environment variables with C in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, environment-variables

Is there a way to enumerate environment variables and retrieve values using C?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take a look at the [`environ`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/environ) global variable.

```
extern char **environ;
```

It might be defined in [`unistd.h`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html) (take a look at the `environ (5)` man page above).

Here's a little code demo I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    for (char **env = environ; *env; ++env)
        printf("%s\n", *env);
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
matt@stanley:~/Desktop$ make enumenv CFLAGS=-std=c99
cc -std=c99    enumenv.c   -o enumenv
matt@stanley:~/Desktop$ ./enumenv 
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-matt
SSH_AGENT_PID=1474
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
... (so forth)
```

Comment: It's not defined in unistd.h, or if it is, your system is not POSIX compliant. POSIX requires you to explicitly declare `extern char **environ;` if you want to use it.

Comment: @R, +1.  On my system at least, it's only declared in `unistd.h` if `__USE_GNU` is set, which indicates it's an extension.  (FWIW, `__environ`, also an extension, is declared unconditionally).

Comment: @R..: up until the POSIX 2008 standard, you were correct; since then, [`<unistd.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/environ.html) has taken the sensible step of requiring it.  It was the only variable without a declaration in a system header.   The only oddball left that I know of is [`union semun`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html).

Comment: Apologies; I stand corrected. I've read previous versions of POSIX in detail but have not gotten around to reading POSIX 2008.

Comment: @Jonathan, didn't know about this `semun` thing. scary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in your link I read “which must be declared by the user if it is to be used directly” and I see no mention if it in [unistd.h(0) 2013 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html). Looks like `extern char **environ;` is still necessary… Did they revert this change since 2008?

Comment: @binki: There was a technical corrigendum for it in IEEE Std 1003.1TM-2008/Cor 1-2013 (which can be obtained from https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/U130; you have to sign up to get it — but the sign-up is free).  The old text was: _In addition, the following variable:
 `extern char **environ;`_ but it was revised to: _In addition, the following variable, which must be declared by the user if it is to be used directly: `extern char **environ;`_  So, it is necessary to declare `environ` once more.

Answer (score 10):

The environment information can be passed as an extra parameter to main. I don't know if it is compliant or not, but it definitely works (tested on Ubuntu). Just define the extra argument and its an array of char pointers terminated by a NULL pointer. The following will print out the lot.

```
#include <stdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  int index = 0;
  while (envp[index])
    printf("%s\n", envp[index++];
}
```

Comment: In practice this works on most unices, but it's not specified by POSIX. Use `extern char **environ;`.

Comment: As Jonathan responded to one of my other comments, as of POSIX 2008 it *is* now part of unistd.h.

Comment: while (*envp) printf("%s\n", *envp++); saves the index variable.

Comment: I just found this out by accidentally reading past the end of argv. Apparently it's there even if you don't have that parameter in the source.

Answer (score 2):

There is a demo in the book "The Linux Programming Interface" at page 127.

Listing 6-3: Displaying the process environment
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––proc/display_env.c

```
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"

extern char **environ;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **ep;
    for (ep = environ; *ep != NULL; ep++)
        puts(*ep);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```