# How to get all environment variables set by a C program itself?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

I am writing a C program that sets environment variables using system() function.

Is there any collection which can give me the environment variables which were set by C program? I need to use the collection in the C program.

Comment: Why don't you just remember them? And why would you use `system` for this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are many environment variables. That's why need to iterate through all.

Comment: If you are creating them, why don't you just remember them? And again, why would you use `system` to do something that is well supported by the library?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan system I used, because I was executing different linux API calls from C Program. And I need to declare environment variables for that.

Comment: You don't need `system` to set environment variables. Use `setenv`.

Comment: Exactly. `system()` is a bad function anyway, and you should avoid if ever possible. As @DavidHeffernan suggested, just use `setenv()`. The library can do this already, and you can store the value of the variable in a variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List environment variables with C in UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473692/list-environment-variables-with-c-in-unix)

Comment: Use setenv() and getenv() instead, and save into an array the list of environment variables that you created into your program and use it to iterate to use getenv().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, and similar systems, when you run a process (such as executing a C program), the process is a **child process** of the process that creates it (usually a command-line shell or a desktop/GUI manager). The creating process is the **parent process**. Any “environment variables” set in the child process do not affect the parent process.

The child process can examine its own environment variables with `getenv`.

If the child process creates its own child process, with `system` or another routine, any environment variables created in that “grandchild” process will not affect its parent (our first child process).

Two common ways for a program to provide environment variables for another process to use are:

- The program may create its own child process and specify environment variables to be created in the child process, as with the various `exec*` routines such as `execle`.
- The program writes settings for environment variables to `stdout` or another stream, and a cooperating process reads those settings and sets its own environment variables accordingly. An example of this is using the command `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` in a Bourne-type shell. This command tells the shell to execute the command `ssh-agent -s` and then to evaluate the output of that command as if it were commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized way to access all environment variables to my knowledge, but almost all systems support declaring a `main` function with a third argument, which will then receive a NULL-terminated array of strings which reflect the entirety of the environment:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char **p;

    for(p = envp; *p != NULL; p++)
        printf("%s\n", *p);
    return(0);
}
```

That should print all environment variables.

Comment: Actually, Posix defines the global `char **environ`, and that is modified by `setenv` so it is a standardized way of accessing all environment variables.

Comment: @rici: Are you sure? I'm not getting it on my system unless I pass `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to the compiler.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html  You have to declare it yourself; it's not in any standard header. But it is still defined by Posix.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's an unusual convention, but it explains it. :)